# Replace value of a dictionary from an other dictionary based on value and key

Tags: python, dictionary

I am a beginner in Python so maybe the answer is really easy, I found many information to update a dictionary value based on other dictionary value but always with the same keys.

I have two dictionaries. One is:

```
global_informations = {"id": "ID_PRODUIT",
                       "name": "NOM_PRODUIT",
                       "type_fdes": "PRODUIT_TYPE",
                       "nb_refs_commerciales": "NB_REF_COMM",
                       "quantite_unit_fonct": "QUANTITE_UF",
                       "type_unit_fonct": "ID_UNIT_UF",
                       "duree_vie": "DVT",
                       "carbon_biogenique": "CARBONE_BIO"
}
```

In this directory, `PRODUIT_TYPE` is an **int** (1,2 or 3)
I want to replace this value based on this dictionary:

```
type_fdes_dictionary = {1: "individuel",
                        2: "collectif",
                        3: "defaut"
}
```

For example if I have:

```
global_informations = {"id": "ID_PRODUIT",
                               "name": "NOM_PRODUIT",
                               "type_fdes": 1,
                               "nb_refs_commerciales": "NB_REF_COMM",
                               "quantite_unit_fonct": "QUANTITE_UF",
                               "type_unit_fonct": "ID_UNIT_UF",
                               "duree_vie": "DVT",
                               "carbon_biogenique": "CARBONE_BIO"
}
```

I want:

```
global_informations = {"id": "ID_PRODUIT",
                       "name": "NOM_PRODUIT",
                       "type_fdes": "individuel",
                       "nb_refs_commerciales": "NB_REF_COMM",
                       "quantite_unit_fonct": "QUANTITE_UF",
                       "type_unit_fonct": "ID_UNIT_UF",
                       "duree_vie": "DVT",
                       "carbon_biogenique": "CARBONE_BIO"
}
```

How can I replace this value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a one liner:
`global_informations["quantite_unit_fonct"] = type_fdes_dictionary[global_informations["quantite_unit_fonct"]]`

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think I could do it so easily! I successfully integrate it to my function

Answer (score 0):

```
    global_informations = {"id": "ID_PRODUIT",
                       "name": "NOM_PRODUIT",
                       "type_fdes": 1,
                       "nb_refs_commerciales": "NB_REF_COMM",
                       "quantite_unit_fonct": "QUANTITE_UF",
                       "type_unit_fonct": "ID_UNIT_UF",
                       "duree_vie": "DVT",
                       "carbon_biogenique": "CARBONE_BIO"
}


type_fdes_dictionary = {1: "individuel",
                        2: "collectif",
                        3: "defaut"
}

print({k: type_fdes_dictionary.get(v, v) for k, v in global_informations.items()})
```

output: {'id': 'ID_PRODUIT', 'name': 'NOM_PRODUIT', **'type_fdes': 'individuel'**, 'nb_refs_commerciales': 'NB_REF_COMM', 'quantite_unit_fonct': 'QUANTITE_UF', 'type_unit_fonct': 'ID_UNIT_UF', 'duree_vie': 'DVT', 'carbon_biogenique': 'CARBONE_BIO'}

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you can do this -

1. via for loop -

```
for key,value in global_informations.items():
    if key=='type_fdes':
        global_informations[key] = type_fdes_dictionary[value]
```

2. One-liner

```
global_informations['type_fdes'] = type_fdes_dictionary[global_informations['type_fdes']]
```